# setting selected option in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a following code in aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtSupplierCountry" class="form-control" Width="230px" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select gender" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="female" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a value in database as male/female. I need to set this text using C# code. Basically I am trying to set selected option based on the text from database. I am not getting an idea. I have tried following code but it doesn't work.

```
String t = "male" // coming from db
txtSupplierCountry.Items.FindByText(t).Selected = true;
```

Comment: `txtSupplierCountry.SelectedValue = "value";` But you have 2 ListItems with the same value, don't do that.

Comment: you can do on razor syntex by adding @{ // c# code }

Answer (score 1):

when you are saving data **Male and Female** then why did you keep dropdown values in number like 1,2 etc, change code like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtSupplierCountry" class="form-control" Width="230px" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Country" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="male" Value="male"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="female" Value="female"></asp:ListItem>
```

then

```
txtSupplierCountry.SelectedValue="male";
```